# ListOrderedMap/ArrayMap like data structure in Javascript

Tags: javascript, data-structures, array-map

I'm looking for a JavaScript data structure like ListOrderedMap:
http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/map/ListOrderedMap.html

E.g. It needs to be able add an object at an index, get the index for an object, and able to look up a object by it's id.

All the libraries I could find couldn't add an object at a certain index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Javascript doesn't have such the data structure, another solution is to use GWT and use the Java source code of ListOrderedMap.java.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?  Javascript has excellent facilities for arrays and keyed collections, and combinations thereof.

```
function LAM() {
    this.ids = {}
    this.indexes = []
}

LAM.prototype.put = function(myObj, id, ix) {
   this.ids[id]  = myObj
   this.indexes[ix] = id
}

LAM.prototype.getByIndex = function(ix) {
    return this.ids[this.indexes[ix]]
}
```

In practice:

```
? a = new LAM

? a.put("jhgf", "WE", 3)

? a.ids.WE
    jhgf

? a.getByIndex(3)
    jhgf
```

Comment: Ah yep good to know. But using 2 data structures like would slow down when I work with a large amount of data. It would be O(N) on remove, get index by id would be O(N), inserting by index would be O(N) etc... But I could use this for the prototype application.

Comment: You may be surprised at how fast it is with large structures. I have been a couple of times. I think it's because the array/keyed collection/object are all one native data type instead of an add-on.